# Prevent editor from adding script or form

Tags: security, editor, visual-editor

For security reasons (e.g. preventing an editor to create a form that mimics the login form and send the credentials anywhere), we'd like to forbid editors to insert JavaScript or Forms into the pages.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

By default, editors and admins in a single site installation have the `unfiltered_html` capability, which means they can insert any JavaScript and forms. If you want to disallow that, you can remove that capability from the editor role as described in [Why is javascript allowed in my post content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235033/why-is-javascript-allowed-in-my-post-content/235037#235037) or using a plugin like [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

The only alternative is to assign them another role. See [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) on which roles have the `unfiltered_html` capability and which don't.